# Custom OData Service has missing property on iOS SAP Cloud Platform app

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

In order to understand the OData <-> SAP Cloud Platform link, I have developed my own minimal OData Service using the Jaystack OData V4 server (https://jaydata.org/jaystack-odata-v4-server) library for Node.js.

To start with, I added a single property - "ID".

Here's the metadata file:

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
        <edmx:DataServices>
            <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Northwind">
                <EntityType Name="Repair">
                    <Key>
                        <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                    </Key>
                    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false">
                        <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Computed" Bool="true"/>
                        <Annotation Term="UI.DisplayName" String="ZSRE Return Document Number"/>
                        <Annotation Term="UI.ControlHint" String="ReadOnly"/>
                    </Property>
                </EntityType>
                <EntityContainer Name="DefaultContainer">
                    <EntitySet Name="Repair" EntityType="Northwind.Repair"/>
                </EntityContainer>
            </Schema>
        </edmx:DataServices>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

When I generate the app using this service as a destination, everything works fine:

[image: Screenshot of the generated app showing all entities with the single 'ID' property]

As soon as I attempt to add another property to my OData model - e.g. "myOtherProperty", I get the following message when re-generating and running the app:

[image: Missing property error when running the re-generated app]

When I take a look at the raw JSON from the service, the property "myOtherProperty" which it complains is missing is clearly there:

```
    {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:3000/$metadata#Repair","value":[{"@odata.id":"http://localhost:3000/Repair('5065879381')","ID":5065879381,"**myOtherProperty**":2311671387},{"@odata.id":"http://localhost:3000/Repair('7651842623')","ID":7651842623,"**myOtherProperty**":3928577920}]
```

Here's the updated schema:

```xml
    <edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Northwind">
    <EntityType Name="Repair">
    <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false">
    <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Computed" Bool="true"/>
    <Annotation Term="UI.DisplayName" String="ZSRE Return Document Number"/>
    <Annotation Term="UI.ControlHint" String="ReadOnly"/>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="myOtherProperty" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="DefaultContainer">
    <EntitySet Name="Repair" EntityType="Northwind.Repair"/>
    </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

Any idea why the SDK could be complaining about a missing property? It seems that with other sample OData services this doesn't appear to be an issue, so I'm guessing it's related to the joystick library, or perhaps a small quirk.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that this question is not related to the `sap-cloud-sdk`. I'm not sure whether there's a tag for the SAP iOS SDK on StackOverflow, maybe you have more luck on another platform.

Comment: Ahh my bad, thanks for pointing that out!